# Root user has no access to bucket policy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have created a new S3 bucket and I am following the below tutorial to host a static website. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/HostingWebsiteOnS3Setup.html#step3-edit-block-public-access

However when it comes to setting the bucket policy, it states that the root user has no access to manage bucket policy. If I follow the links and traverse to the IAM console, there are no other users but me the root user. How can the root user grant himself the bucket permissions?

Comment: You have to create an IAM user to use: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/getting-started_create-admin-group.html. The root user should only be used to manage billing.

Comment: This sounds highly unusual. The root user should be able to edit the bucket policy. Make sure you have turned off S3 Block Public Access -- there are two options related to Bucket Policies that should be deactivated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It wont allow setting a bucket policy if you have not cleared the Block All Public Access button. I had not cleared that and it was resulting in this invalid permissions error.